# Make labels for mathematical plot face always the camera

Tags: text-object

In a mathematical plot, the labels (the numers on the tick-marks) for the coordinate axes usually always face the camera like in this plot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've learned that in Blender, you can achieve this by setting *Track To* constraints on the text.

[image: blend]

Three questions:

1. Is this the best way to do it for text?
2. The docu for [Track To](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/tracking/track_to.html) is rather short. What is the correct setting to make the text face the camera and why?
3. Is anyone aware of a script that possibly creates such a box, the ticks, and the labels automatically? Maybe this was already done for plotting mathematical surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it's the best way ; unless a script exists that allows billboard rendering for text object, but I don't know any.
2. Displaying the Axis of the text object helps a lot!

"To" is the axis that points to the target ; for a text object, it's Z.
"Up" is the axis that point upwards ; for a text object, it's Y.

[image]